# VO.executeQuery() sets RowIterator at first row

Tags: java, rest, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I am new to ADF Framework and JDeveloper. I have come across this behaviour of ViewObject in ADF. I am calling a **REST Service(Custom method)** on a **ViewObject(i.e. VO)** which invokes a method(lets call it **captureSomething**) in its **implementation class(i.e. VOImpl.java)**. In the captureSomething method, I am doing something like the following piece of code:

```
vo.applyCriteria(someCriteria);
vo.setNamedWhereClause(/* Some parameters set here */);
vo.executeQuery();
System.out.println(vo.getCurrentRowIndex());
```

The System.out.println(vo.getCurrentRowIndex()), sometimes, **prints -1** and sometimes **prints 0**. But in all cases, one row has been returned on executeQuery(). Doesn't the RowIterator get reset upon running **vo.executeQuery()**? Did the executeQuery() fail to run during the times it printed 0?

I looked this up online trying to find out why this happens but couldn't find anything.

Not sure if this is relevant or has anything to do with this behaviour but I am attaching some code for reference:

I have an **Application Module** called **RestAM** and in its **DataModel**, we have **VO**. Added a **REST WebService** in **RestAM** and added **VO** as a resource.

I have created a **custom method** for **VO** in **RestAM_VOResources.xml.**

```
<methodAction IterBinding="VOIter" id="captureSomething"
              RequiresUpdateModel="true" Action="invokeMethod"
              MethodName="captureSomething"
              IsViewObjectMethod="false"
              DataControl="RestAMDataControl"
              InstanceName="bindings.VOIter"
              IsLocalObjectReference="true">
  <NamedData NDName="param1" NDType="java.lang.Long"/>
  <NamedData NDName="param2" NDType="java.sql.Date"/>
</methodAction>
```

I have created a **captureSomething** method in the **VOImpl.java**(The implementation class of VO). Code is similar to the first piece of code that I have attached above.

Comment: Row 0 sounds like "the first row" and row -1 sounds like "no rows returned".

Comment: I'm sorry I did not add this earlier, I'll edit the question. But in all cases one row has been returned.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28430467/view-criteria-not-returning-row

This person maybe facing the same issue as me, hence he has come up with that answer.
vo.next() might have returned null because the rowIterator was not reset after executeQuery(). Hence he is using vo.first().

Comment: Hi Manoj. What's your issue ?

Comment: Hi @Cedric,
My code is turning out to be buggy because of this inconsistency. The bug arose because, after vo.executeQuery(), vo.getCurrentRowIndex() returned 0 instead of -1.
I did not understand why the currentRowIndex() returned 0. In every case of vo.executeQuery(), there was one row returned.
My question is, why wasn't the rowIndex reset on executeQuery()?
Now, when I am trying to debug the service, it returns -1. I am unable to replicate this issue and hence unable to provide a fix because I don't know why it was coming up?